# Prevent deployment of service if supporting services aren't yet deployed with octopus

Tags: octopus-deploy

We have a distributed system with many services which talk to each other.

Sometimes a code change in one service will require a feature to have been deployed in another service.

We use octopus to deploy all the things which is cool but we really want to prevent services from being deployed before the things they depend on are deployed.

Is there a way we can do this with octopus deploy?

For example can I make the nuget package for one service depend on an explicit version range of another package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to deploy all your projects as one massive deployment with a series of steps that push your different services to different machines, then I don't think there's a built-in way to make your deployments dependent on each other's version numbers like that. (see [this uservoice suggestion in Octopus](https://octopusdeploy.uservoice.com/forums/170787-general/suggestions/9811932-allow-project-dependencies-so-deploying-one-proj) asking for that very feature)

However, I do think that you could write a powershell script that ran as a pre-deployment step and checked the version number of one nuget package against a version range stored in another. Then the ps script could halt or allow deployment accordingly.

Comment: Its a shame this isn't in there but good find on the feature request. Its interesting someone just posted that recently (it wasn't me)

Comment: Yeah, I wondered if I was just being cruel and linking you your own request. Upvotin' time I guess!